# What is the shortcut key for hide all doc lines in Intellij editor?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, javadoc, shortcut

I want to hide doc lines in [Intellij](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) like:

[image]
[image]

Is there any shortcut key for hide all doc comments at once in Intellij?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have all documentation comments hidden by default, just go to *Settings/Editor/Code Folding* and check *Documentation comments*. You might need to restart IntelliJ or close opened files for it to take effect.

---

If you want to hide/show all documentation comments in the current file, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and select *Collapse doc comments*/*Expand doc comments*. You can even bind a shortcut to these actions in *Settings/Keymap* if you plan on using them frequently.